# How to manage PHP odbc_exec timeout?

Tags: php, timeout, odbc

I've got a command-line PHP script that connects to SQL Server 2005 using an ODBC connection.  It uses odbc_exec() to execute a stored procedure which may take a while to process, and I don't want it to timeout.

I've been unable to find anything in the PHP documentation regarding how to set the timeout for odbc_exec().  Does it default to an infinite wait?

Answer (score 2):

There's only so much you can do here.  PHP's default script execution time is set to 30 seconds.  There are numerous ways to change this, including the `set_time_limit()` function (found in the manual), and extending execution time by using `ini_set`, or using `odbc_setoption`

```
//extend execution time
$num_minutes = 5;
ini_set('max_execution_time', (60*$num_minutes)); //set timeout to 5 minutes
```

You can also change this setting inside your php.ini file.  However, all of these only control the scope within what your apache server can control.  If the database itself has a timeout, it will still cut off your call and return an error, even if your personally set execution times are elevated.

Comment: I'm using PHP in batch, hence the CLI version, which hardcodes max_execution_time to zero.

Answer (score 1):

According to php.net you can use  `odbc_setoption()`:

```
$result = odbc_prepare($conn, $sql);
odbc_setoption($result, 2, 0, 30);// 30 seconds timeout
odbc_execute($result);
```

So you can increase timeout to some bigger number depending on your need

Comment: Oh, so I should use odbc_execute() instead of odbc_exec().  I'll give that a try, thanks!