# PHP odbc connection timeout report

Tags: php, sql-server

I am using PHP to make an ODBC to a MS SQL Server 2012 database. My query results were not coming in because there is an automatic timeout for the `odbc_exec` command. I have changed my code (and it now is working) to

```
$myQuery = odbc_prepare($myConnection, $mySQLQuery);
odbc_setoption($myQuery, 2, 0, 6000); // 100 minute timeout
odbc_execute($myQuery);
```

as per the suggestion of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15278513/6561382). I am wondering how I can tell if this query does time out, so that I can report it as an error or something of that sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation, I have come up with the following solution, please let me know if you have a better one!

Running my program in the command prompt with the argument `-d display_errors` gave the warning:

> SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Query timeout expired, SQL state S1T00 in SQLExecute in myPHPfile.php on line 31

From here, I used the basic idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3316953/6561382) as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4366748/6561382) technique to create my own error handler and do something special when the query timed out as follows

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if (strpos($errstr, "Query timeout expired") !== false && $errno = E_WARNING){ 
        # If there is a warning with text containing "Query timeout expired"
        # Do your handling here
    }

    # Execute PHP internal error handler as well
    return false;
}

set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
```

I searched the string for "Query timeout expired" because most likely there are other `$errstr` messages, depending on the ODBC; you may have to fiddle with this to make it work for you. I returned `false` in my custom error handler so the default handler would also run.